# useState not working as expected inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I want to keep track of whether the user is on top of the page or has scrolled down to change the header accordingly. Here is my code.

```
const [isTop, changeIsTop] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
  const handleScroll = () => {
    changeIsTop(window.scrollY < 100)
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  }
}, [])
```

`changeisTop` does not do anything. `isTop` is always set to its initial value. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why are you using `[]` ? I guess removing that should resolve your issue

Comment: No. It won't. He is passing `[ ]` to ensure the effect will only run once

Comment: What if scroll happens after first effect?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/late-leaf-mnncu?fontsize=14. Your code seens to work just fine

Comment: I think you should have `handleScroll` outside of `useEffect`.

Comment: Can you put the complete code in tools like https://codesandbox.io/ ? This can help us understand better what happen :)

Comment: Not he shouldn't. This will throw a warning from `eslint` for non declared dependencies. This code works, your problem is on the implementation for sure

Comment: I agree with @Dupocas. This code is working fine. I would suggest to console and see the value of `window.scrollY < 100`. You might be seeing `true` always because this condition is returning true. Just to make sure your code works, simply hardcode false for time being and check.

Comment: @Dupocas you are right. But why does console log of `isTop` always returns true inside it. https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-edison-dbef5?fontsize=14. Can you please check this and let me know ? I got confused because of this.

Comment: I'll answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine. You're setting the event listener in the right way.

```
useEffect(() =>{
    const listener = () => {}
    window.addEventListener('click', listener)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('click', listener)
},[])
```

This effect will only run in the component's first mount (equivalent to `componentDidMount`). When your component gets mounted the listener is attached to a global `click` event, and everytime a `click` happens `listener` will be invoked. Your problem is where you're printing the value. Remember, `useEffect` will only run once, so if you `console.log` inside the `useEffect` you will see it's initial value (before `listener` gets attached).

```
useEffect(() =>{
    const listener = () => {}
    window.addEventListener('click', listener)
    console.log('only run once')
    return () => window.removeEventListener('click', listener)
},[])
```

To `console.log` the correct value, put it outside `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() =>{
    const listener = () => {}
    window.addEventListener('click', listener)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('click', listener)
},[])
console.log('run every render')
```

[image: Edit late-leaf-mnncu]

Comment: So you are saying inside useEffect isTop will be it's initial value. Closure is not working then, correct ?. Traditionally a function should enclose a variable even though it is not in it's scope.

Comment: I'm saying that when `useEffect` is running (first mount) isTop is `false` (initial value) and will ony change when `scroll` happens. So by the time you're logging `isTop` no `scroll` event happened yet

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-edison-dbef5?fontsize=14. Then why in this sandbox isTop always return true on console even on scroll? The line below that should change it's value.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine (tested), only thing I'd suggest is registering your callback only once on initial mount:

```
 const [isTop, changeIsTop] = useState(true);

 const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    changeIsTop(window.scrollY < 100)
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
    return () => { window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll) }
  }, [handleScroll])
```

> But why does console log of isTop always returns true inside it.

Your initial `isTop` value is `true`. Since `useEffect` is ran on initialMount, `isTop` (which is `true`) is passed in `handleScroll` callback. Whenever scroll is detected, `handleScroll` will be triggered but not in context of your component, which means that `isTop` inside your callback will not be reassigned.

Try setting

```
const [isTop, changeIsTop] = React.useState('bla');
```

and you'll se that if you `console.log(isTop)` inside `handleScroll`, `isTop` will be 'bla' (string forever!!), but within your component it will be transformed to `boolean` after first `changeIsTop(window.scrollY < 100)` occurs.